# Synchronization in abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, synchronization

I am working on Java Event Manager, and I want to add new future to it. 
It is custom class selection, or custom matching class system.

```
EventManager eventManager = new EventManager();
```

Ways how to set new class selector to event manager:

```
eventManager.setClassSelector(Class<? extends ClassSelector> classSelector);
eventManager.setClassSelector(ClassSelector classSelector);
```

This method using class selector:

```
eventManager.callEvent(event);
```

There is structure of ClassSelector

```
public abstract class ClassSelector{
    public List<Class<?>> classSelection(Class<?> clazz);
}
```

Method *classSelection* in ClassSelector must be synchronized, because callEvent is using ThreadPool with multiple Threads and only one instance of ClassSelector.

But synchronize key word is not inherited from super class. I need advice, how to solve this problem, by changing code or by changing logic.

Comment: Unrelated: look into your method naming. Normally they go verbObject. So `classSelection()` isn't ideal ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple: when your **abstract base class** needs to "restrict" a method in a certain way (like: you want to enforce the method is `synchronized`) - then that method should not be abstract.

Instead implement that method and make it **final**:

```
public abstract class ClassSelector{
   public final synchronized List<Class<?>> getClassSelection(Class<?> clazz) {
     return getSpecificClasses(clazz);
   }

   protected abstract List<Class<?>> getSpecificClasses(Class<?> clazz);
```

Now it is clear that a **user** of your class should call that public method - and that each subclass can only implement something that is *guaranteed* to be called in a synchronized manner.

(method naming isn't really great - just meant as example)

Answer (score 2):

You could make `classSelection` a real method, that calls an abstract method.  Each subclass would then only supply an implementation of the abstract method.  This could look something like this.

```
public abstract class ClassSelector{
    public synchronized final List<Class<?>> classSelection(Class<?> clazz) {
        return doClassSelection(clazz);
    }
    protected List<Class<?>> doClassSelection(Class<?> clazz);
}
```

The `final` prevents someone from overriding your restriction, and implementing their own non-synchronized version of `classSelection`.

Comment: Maybe I got  the last one!